# Match at start of line \d or \d\d

Tags: regex

I am trying to match the start of these lines to get the number

```
1 - blah
01 - blah
```

I expect

```
1
01
```

I have this regex but dont understand why the second part is not matching 01

```
((^\d)|(^\d\d))
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern is not matching for incorrect placing of `^`.

- `^` would match the start of a string unless you use `Mode modifier` or other `options`.

**Try this**

```
(?im)^(\d+)\b
```

**Explanation**

```
<!--
(?im)^(\d+)\b

Match the remainder of the regex with the options: case insensitive (i); ^ and $ match at line breaks (m) «(?im)»
Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character) «^»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\d+)»
   Match a single digit 0..9 «\d+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Assert position at a word boundary «\b»
-->
```

Comment: If you want specifically the first two digits if there is a longer number, you could use `^(\d{1,2})` or equivalently `^(\d\d?)`